# como iniciar video automaticamente do youtube em iframe sem ser pelo autoplay?

Tags: php, javascript, html

como eu poderia fazer isso nesse codigo abaixo

```
<iframe width="420" height="345" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Y3wtmZ4Ds3M?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

não importa a linguagem de programação

Comment: Já verificou a saída do console do seu navegador?

Comment: Aqui funcionou normal.

Comment: quero fazer fucina sem o autoplay que ta no codigo :C mais acho que não da pra fazer isso

Comment: Por que exatamente? Qual a diferença de com e sem?

Comment: Qual a finalidade que o `autoplay` na URL não sirva? Se for para gerar `views` ao vídeo, nenhuma alterativa funcionará.

Comment: com o autoplay o video não fica monetizado

Comment: @Edu não adianta querer trapacear o Google, é totalmente possivel distinguir um clique feito por um humano para o play de um clique robótico.

Comment: pse google é foda kkk obg pela ajuda

Comment: Estou votando para fechar esta pergunta como fora de escopo porque viola os termos de uso do youtube

Answer (score 3):

### Se o intuito é monetizar

Mesmo que seja possível forçar o play simulando que foi um humano que clicou no play com o intuito de monetizar o Youtube vai saber a diferença, a Google é a criadora do *reCaptcha* e agora do [*reCaptcha "invisível"*](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2017/03/googles-recaptcha-announces-invisible-background-captchas/), acha que realmente seria capaz de burlar algo que uma empresa inteira com vários profissionais criaram para evitar? Creio que não.

Isso é claramente uma segurança para evitar cliques falsos e eles estão corretos em fazer isto, a intenção de assistir o vídeo tem que vir da parte do usuário.

### Para outros usos

Acaso Aqui este vídeo funcionou normalmente, todavia a alternativa seria usar o [**Youtube API**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference), assim:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="player"></div>

    <script>
    (function () {
        var player;

        window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
            player = new YT.Player('player', {
                height: '390',
                width: '640',
                videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
                events: {
                    'onReady': onPlayerReady
                }
            });
        };

        // 4. Executa o play quando o video estiver pronto
        function onPlayerReady(event) {
            event.target.playVideo();
        }

        var tag = document.createElement('script');

        tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
        var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
    })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```